# visual basic .net program for xp platform program is being built on windows 7

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

i am running visual studio 2008 visual studio 2010 vs 2012 on windows 7 platform with visual basics windows form application. No matter what i do , installing and targeting .net frame work 3.5 or older . The EXECUTABLE file built in this setup fails to run on windows xp SP3. what am i missing ?

Problem is being reported it as invalid win32 application , faulty start-point!

Comment: Do you have the .net framework 3.5 installed on the xp machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something similar issue a few years ago, but in reverse.

It might not be a .NET version issue though: it might be a 32 / 64 bit problem.  After spending a lot of time on .NET framework requirements and re-re-reinstalling, once I compiled to 32 bit rather than Any CPU it would run on XP SP3 (even though it was 64 bit XP).